# How to partition MatrixPlot graphics?

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation

Is there an easy approach - hopefully built-in - to partitioning `MatrixPlot` graphics into rows or columns (or both) of graphics sharing the same underlying options?

For example, in the following graphic, the red rectangles indicate where partitions should occur, and the respective sub-Rasters (along with `FrameTicks` etc) can then be reorganized using `Row`

[image]

This particular graph (excluding the rectangles which were generated in `Epilog`) has `Length` 6, of which all but the first `Part` are related to options. But it's tedious to even list what parts of the partitions component correspond to which parts, which subsequently must be modified - for example `FrameTicks` are to be repositioned (reindexed).

Obviously, because the "heatmap" color scale is shared among all the members of the desired partition, it's not feasible to partition the matrix prior and then mapping through `MatrixPlot`

Comment: Please explain "sharing the same underlying options".

Comment: For example, the `ColorData`, the FrameLabels.. any option passed to the original `MatrixPlot`

Comment: I'd suggest setting up a custom Blend function based on the pooling of your data, and then building a `Grid` of the subplots. See [my recent post on the Mathematica.SE blog](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/turning-up-the-heat-maps/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment, I think the recent [post I wrote for the Mathematica.SE blog](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/turning-up-the-heat-maps/) will be useful. To summarize:

1. Build a custom temperature scale color function using `Blend` and your pooled dataset.
2. Use `BaseStyle` and related options with a pre-defined set of option value rules to enforce similar styles across the subplot.
3. Use `Grid`, not `GraphicsGrid` to combine plots with different widths.

Here is an example, using the same tick labels as in the blog post. First, here's some data, specified as a 3D list. Notice how I've used the general iteration capabilities of `Table` to create a list of two 5 by 10 matrices and two 3 by 10 matrices.

```
heatdata = 
  Table[RandomVariate[
    LogNormalDistribution[0, 2], {i, 10}], {i, {5, 5, 3, 3}}];
```

Next we define the custom `Blend` to scale across the whole data set. Note that `Min` and `Max` work for the whole data set even though it's a nested list, but you need to `Flatten` the data before applying `Mean`.

```
myblend = 
 Evaluate@Blend[{{Min[heatdata], Blue}, {Mean[Flatten@heatdata], 
      White}, {Max[heatdata], Orange}}, #] &

(* Blend[{{0.00629577, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, {6.37397, 
    GrayLevel[1]}, {215.341, RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]}}, #1] & *)
```

You can now `Map` the `MatrixPlot` function to each matrix in the data set. Notice that I'm also using a pure function to determine the approprate `AspectRatio` so it all fits together nicely. Then it's just a matter of partitioning the plots the way you want and applying `Grid`.

```
Grid[Partition[
  MatrixPlot[#, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     AspectRatio -> Divide @@ Dimensions[#], ColorFunction -> myblend,
      FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     FrameTicks -> {{ytix, None}, {xtix, None}}] & /@ heatdata, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: (1) In my situation, the TickMarks will not be the same across plots, since they are partitioned from the original TickMarks. (2) is it possible to selectively suppress some TickMarks for some (but not all) of the partitioned plots? For example, only show F1...Fn along the y-axis of only the leftmost pair of plots (and similarly for E1...Em along the x-axis for only the bottom plots)?