# Adding space between rows in ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to add space between rows and/or columns in `ArrayPlot`?

From this

```
 ArrayPlot[Table[x*y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}], Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 25]
```

[image]

i would like to get something like this

[image]

I tried the following code but obviously it is not work as desired

```
  (ArrayPlot[{#}, Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 25]) & /@ Table[x*y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: "add space between rows and/or columns in `ArrayPlot`" - with `ArrayPlot` itself, no; you may need to fall back with using `Raster[]`.

Comment: related: [How to partition MatrixPlot graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11625/125)

Answer (score 5):

ArrayPlot may not be the best tool for this kind of thing. Here is a way using GraphicsGrid that allows quite flexible control over the appearance.

```
tab = Table[x*y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}]; 
GraphicsGrid[Table[g = (Max[tab] - tab[[i, j]])/Max[tab];
    Graphics[{RGBColor[g, g, g], EdgeForm[Directive[Black]], Rectangle[]}],
        {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 20}], Spacings -> {20, 200}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

You can control the overall size with ImageSize. Control the vertical and 
horizontal spaces with the two Spacings parameters. Control the color with the RGBColor parameter. The EdgeForm directives control the appearance of the edges.

Comment: Nice! But how I can make spacing in row really equal to zero? Since if I put Spacings -> {0, 200} there are still gaps between cells

Comment: Use negative numbers. Spacings -> {-20, 200} seems about right.

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayPlot[Table[x y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}], 
  Mesh -> True,
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 25,
  MeshStyle -> {{White, Thickness[0.02]}, {White, Thickness[0.02]}}]
```

Comment: almost, but I would like to keep the borders around the cells

Comment: also it reduce the size of the cells ArrayPlot[Table[x y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}], Mesh -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 1 -> 35, 
 MeshStyle -> {{White, Thickness[0.02]}, {White, Thickness[0.00]}}]

Comment: I can't seem to find that `ImageSize` specification. Where is it in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

```
table = Table[x*y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}];
```

**Using ArrayPlot with PlotRange -> {0, Max[table]}:**

[ArrayPlot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html):

> With the default setting for *ColorFunction*, *PlotRange->{$a_{min}$, $a_{max}$}* specifies that values from *$a_{min}$* to *$a_{max}$* should be shown with gray scales varying from white to black.

```
Column[ArrayPlot[{#}, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, PlotRange -> {0, Max[table]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .1, ImagePadding -> .1] & /@ table, Spacings -> .5]
```

[image]

**Using ListDensityPlot:**

```
data = 1 - table/Max[table]; 

Column[ListDensityPlot[{#, #}, InterpolationOrder -> {0, 0}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/20, Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Antialiasing -> False, GrayLevel[-1 + GoldenRatio]], 
  Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 1 -> 40] & /@ data, Spacings -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following approach relies on `ArrayPlot` to generate an appropriately colored and scaled `Raster` object. I then extract the data and specifications from this object (size, scale), and split the data up into rows, each one of which is used to generate a new `Raster` object with the specifications obtained above, but appropriately resized. The objects obtained, i.e. the "rows" of the original `ArrayPlot` are then re-combined using `Column` to introduce spacing. The process is wrapped in a custom function called `spacedArray`:

```
Clear[spacedArray]
spacedArray[data_?MatrixQ] := Block[
  {values, rectangle, range},
  {values, rectangle, range} = First@Cases[
     ArrayPlot[data, Mesh -> True],
     Raster[values_, rectangle_, range_] :> {values, rectangle, range},
     Infinity
   ];
  rectangle[[2, 2]] = rectangle[[2, 2]]/First@Dimensions[values];
  Column[
   Graphics[Raster[{#}, rectangle, range], ImageSize -> 1 -> 25] & /@ values
  ]
]
```

Here is the result on the original toy data:

```
spacedArray[Table[x*y, {x, 4}, {y, 20}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... and on a different data set:

```
spacedArray[Table[x*y, {x, 5}, {y, 10}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that in the latter case the size of the cells is retained, although the overall size and aspect ratio of the plot changes substantially.

Vertical spacing can be controlled with appropriate options to `Column`. Obviously, this solution is still missing the mesh lines: those could be extracted from `ArrayPlot` as well as `Line` objects (two sets of lines, for the horizontal and vertical mesh respectively), but that seems tedious. Perhaps direct construction from `Graphics` primitives would be best at that point.